# Catch which user sends kill signal

Tags: kill, signals

Say I'm running some script that just sleeps, and another user with admin rights tries to kill my script using `pkill`. How can I catch which user sent that signal to my process, if such a thing is possible?

I know that something like `kill -9 <my_script>` won't allow me to catch anything, as we can't catch or do anything with SIGKILL.

Comment: Do you have admin (root) access to the machine? Is the machine running linux?

Comment: Root access? No. Running linux? Yes.

Comment: OK, then my solution monitoring the system calls with ftrace will not work.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, this is possible, albeit perhaps not from a script. For this to work, you need to set your signal handler up using [`sigaction`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sigaction.2.html) with the `SA_SIGINFO` flag, and provide a handler with a signature identical to

```
void handler(int sig, siginfo_t *info, void *ucontext)
```

When it is invoked to handle a signal, the `siginfo_t` pointer it receives as its second argument will contain, among other pieces of information, the process identifier of the sending process (`info->si_pid`), and the read user identifier of the sending process (`info->si_uid`). These are filled in for signals sent using [`kill`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/kill.2.html) or [`sigqueue`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/sigqueue.3.html).

Implementing this in Python would require a fair amount of work, since the [signal module](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/signal.html) doesn’t provide a way of accessing the `siginfo_t` structure.

Comment: Hmmm. I see how this could get tricky for a shell script with many processes created therein... So I'd have to add this logic to each process, basically? How could I do this `handler` logic in just the "runner" shell script itself? I'm fairly sure I could figure out how to handle this in Python (all of my processes in this shell script are from Python), but want to catch anyone trying to kill my topmost shell script.

Comment: Ah yes, I got a bit carried away and forgot this was for a script. I imagine this is possible from Python, but I don’t think it is from a shell script.

Answer (score 3):

### bash + ctypes.sh

Just for fun, using @StephenKitt 's solution, here's an example in bash, using the [bash plugin](https://ss64.com/bash/enable.html) [ctypes.sh](https://github.com/taviso/ctypes.sh) (which must be be compiled and installed in `/usr/local` for this example).

Sadly, both structures `sigaction` and `siginfo_t` are too complex for `ctypes.sh`'s builtin `struct` command to work. Those structures have thus to be manually defined. This is a quite annoying chore, and it's non-portable (both for OS and for architecture). This example assumes Linux >= 4.6 (because of `info->si_pkey`) on x86_64 architecture.

```
#!/bin/bash

. /usr/local/bin/ctypes.sh || exit 2

handler () {
    local -a info=(int int int int uint32 uint32 int int64 int64 int64 int pointer int int pointer long int short pointer pointer int pointer int unsigned)
    unpack $3 info

    echo ''
    echo "handler($2, info={${info[@]}}, $4);"
    echo -- handling signal $2 --
    echo "info->si_pid=${info[4]}"
    echo "info->si_uid=${info[5]}"
    return
}
callback -n handler handler void int pointer pointer

SIGUSR2=12
SA_SIGINFO=4

act=(
    $handler
    long:0 long:0 long:0 long:0 long:0 long:0 long:0 long:0 long:0 long:0 long:0 long:0 long:0 long:0 long:0 long:0
    int:$SA_SIGINFO
    pointer:0
)
sizeof_act=$(( 8 + 16 * 8 + 4 + 8 ))

dlcall -n pact -r pointer malloc $sizeof_act
[ $pact != pointer:0 ] || exit 1
pack $pact act

dlcall -n ret -r int sigaction int:$SIGUSR2 $pact pointer:0
[ $ret = int:0 ] || exit 1

echo "sigaction(SIGUSR2, act={${act[@]}}, NULL) = $ret"

echo ''
echo run this: kill -$SIGUSR2 $$
sleep 99
```

Execution:

term1:

```
$ ./siginfo.bash 
sigaction(SIGUSR2, act={pointer:0x7ff26f0d3010 long:0 long:0 long:0 long:0 long:0 long:0 long:0 long:0 long:0 long:0 long:0 long:0 long:0 long:0 long:0 long:0 int:4 pointer:0}, NULL) = int:0

run this: kill -12 24250
```

term2:

```
$ echo $$
21864
$ id -u
1000
$ kill -12 24250
$
```

result in term1:

```
handler(int:12, info={int:12 int:0 int:0 int:0 uint32:21864 uint32:1000 int:0 int64:0 int64:0 int64:0 int:0 pointer:0 int:0 int:0 pointer:0 long:0 int:0 short:0 pointer:0 pointer:0 int:0 pointer:0 int:0 unsigned:0}, pointer:0x7fff4583a500);
-- handling signal int:12 --
info->si_pid=uint32:21864
info->si_uid=uint32:1000
```