# Use of SEGV signal

Tags: signals

As far as I understand, a `SEGV` signal is sent by the OS to inform a process that it has attempted an illegal memory access.
But I noticed that it is also possible to send a `SEGV` signal to a process from another process (e.g. `kill -s SEGV pid`).

Therefore I was wondering, what is the use of being able to send a `SEGV` signal to another process?

Futhermore, is there anyway for a process to know whether the `SEGV` signal was sent by the OS or by another process?

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/489717/catch-which-user-sends-kill-signal

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Therefore I was wondering, what is the use of being able to send a SEGV signal to another process?

I suppose someone could send it manually for testing. But even if no use for it was thought of originally, we never know if someone might come up with a use, and then arbitrary restrictions would just get in the way.

> Futhermore, is there anyway for a process to know whether the SEGV signal was sent by the OS or by another process?

Yes, as mentioned in [Catch which user sends kill signal](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/489717/catch-which-user-sends-kill-signal), signal handlers set with `sigaction()` with the `SA_SIGINFO` flag can read a number of details from the `siginfo_t` structure. Those contain the reason the signal was sent (`si_code`), and if it applies, the sending user and PID (`si_uid`, `si_pid`).

See the man page: https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sigaction.2.html

Here's a simple program to test that, it sets up a handler for SIGSEGV and sends it to itself, first with `kill()` and then by triggering an invalid memory access:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

void action(int sig, siginfo_t *si, void *p)
{
    printf("sig: %d\n", sig);
    printf("si_signo: %d\n", si->si_signo);
    char *reason = "?";
    switch (si->si_code) {
        case SI_USER: reason = "Signal sent by user"; break;
        case SI_TKILL: reason = "Signal sent by user (tkill)"; break;
        case SI_KERNEL: reason = "Signal sent by kernel"; break;
        case SEGV_MAPERR:
            reason = "SIGSEGV - Address not mapped to object"; break;
        case SEGV_ACCERR: 
            reason = "SIGSEGV - Invalid permissions for mapped object"; break;
    }
    printf("si_code: %d (%s)\n", si->si_code, reason);
    printf("si_pid: %d\n", (int) si->si_pid);
    printf("si_uid: %d\n", (int) si->si_uid);
    printf("si_addr: 0x%016lx\n", (unsigned long) si->si_addr);
    if (si->si_code != SI_USER && si->si_code != SI_TKILL) {
        // if it's an actual error, exit instead of
        // returning to repeat the error 
        _exit(1);
    }
}   

int main(void)
{
    struct sigaction sa = {0}; 
    sa.sa_sigaction = action;
    sa.sa_flags = SA_SIGINFO;
    int ret = sigaction(SIGSEGV, &sa, NULL);
    if (ret == -1) {
        perror("sigaction");
        exit(1);
    }
    printf("raising SIGSEGV manually\n");
    kill(getpid(), SIGSEGV);
    printf("\n");
    printf("trying to trigger SIGSEGV\n");
    volatile int *p = (int *) 0xdeadbeef;
    (void) *p;
}
```

The output on my system is:

```
raising SIGSEGV manually
sig: 11
si_signo: 11
si_code: 0 (Signal sent by user)
si_pid: 13868
si_uid: 1000
si_addr: 0x000003e80000362c

trying to trigger SIGSEGV
sig: 11
si_signo: 11
si_code: 1 (SIGSEGV - Address not mapped to object)
si_pid: -559038737
si_uid: 0
si_addr: 0x00000000deadbeef
```

(Note that some fields that don't apply to the case in question contain garbage.)

Answer (score 1):

Unix puts no restrictions on what signals can be sent to a process.  It only restricts signals based on process ownership.

In general, there is no way to determine the source of a signal.

Comment: "In general, there is no way to determine the source of a signal" - that is not true. You **can** know the source of a signal from within the process that received it. See the following answer (that was already commented to the question by @A.B): https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/489720/273579

Comment: That's why I said "in general" ... that method doesn't work in many cases, like python and shell scripts.  And that comment wasn't there when I wrote this answer.

Comment: @user10489, but _in general_ there is a way to determine the source! the system calls allow for it just fine. It might be that with some script languages _in particular_ it's hard to impossible. But then again the question didn't ask about Python or the shell. And based on the timestamps, the comment was there about 4 h before this answer.